# How to get user's Birthday and gender from google login

Tags: angular, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to implement a google login in my angular application. The google returning name, email, profile picture, ID, access token. Nut How can I get users birthday and gender. I have tried so many ways but nothing worked for me.

I was trying to profile.getGender() and profile.getBirthday() it is throwing error.

```
googleSDK() {

  window['googleSDKLoaded'] = () => {
    window['gapi'].load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = window['gapi'].auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      });
      this.prepareLoginButton();
    });
  }

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=googleSDKLoaded";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'google-jssdk'));

}


ngOnInit() {
  this.googleSDK();
}



prepareLoginButton() {

  this.auth2.attachClickHandler(this.loginElement.nativeElement, {},
    (googleUser) => {

      let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
      console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
      console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
      console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
      console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
      //YOUR CODE HERE


    }, (error) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the following scopes in order to access that data.

- View your complete date of birth: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read
- See your gender: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read

You may then need to go though the people api i am not sure if that information would be return directly with the authorization response.

## check settings in user profile

go to [profile birthday](https://myaccount.google.com/birthday) set it public.

[image]

Comment: My current scope looks like this - 

scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read'

but in the console i am not getting any gender and birthday

Comment: Did you reauthencate the application did it pop up and ask you to grant access to the additional scopes?   I am not an angular dev so i cant help you much more then this.  You need to request the proper scopes and go though the people api.  (which could be what googleUser does)

Comment: Yes google was asking if i want to public my gender and birthday, i have allowed them.
But don't know why those two are not showing

Comment: Did you check that your google account has it set to public?

Comment: yah i have checked it is set to public.

Comment: Im out of ideas sorry